# How do I make a function execute after an asychronous function is completed?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have a function which is processing a large amount of data, so I'm processing the data asynchronously to allow the browser update the the screen. However, I would like to call another function after that asynchronous function has completed its processing. This is what I tried to do.

```
function addObjects(){

object.setSrc(objFilename);
object2.setSrc(objFilname2);

} 

addObjects();
```

However, order doesn't matter for an asynchronous process. How do I make the second function be called after the first asynchronous function has finished processing?

Comment: How do you call your function asynchronously?

Comment: @Jiri no, how to call a function AFTER an asynchronous function. "Because async functions have no concept of time, how do I time another function to be called after it?" Is basically what I'm asking.

Comment: yes, I understood your question, I just wanted to get more information. You are writing: "I'm processing the data asynchronously" and you "would like to call another function after that asynchronous function". So, how are you "processing the data asynchronously"?

Comment: @Jiri I'm using setTimeout(PROCESS,200); The reason I'm doing this is I have a loading gif on the screen and I wanted that loading gif to rotate while the data is being processed. So I'm making it process the loop in bits after every 200 milliseconds and then give it time to update the browser display and allow the gif to spin.

However, I want to call that same asynchronous function on another bit of data but I need the first bit to be done first. For this reason I'm wondering if it is possibly to make a function be called right after an asynchronous function has completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use e.g.

```
setTimeout(process1, 200);
```

to process asynchronously data in the function `process1()` you can can call the other processing function in `process1()`:

```
function process1() {
    // ... process data 1 here
    // when processing data 1 finished then process data 2
    process2();   
}
```

You can also delay the call of `process2()`:

```
function process1() {
    // ... process data 1 here
    // when processing data 1 finished then process data 2 asynchronously, but after data 1
    setTimeout(process2, 200); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cant you add a callback to your function call?

As such:

```
function doSomethingIntensive( callback )
{
  //Do some stuff
  for(var i = 0; i < 10000; i++); //Something intensive

  //we're done, fire the callback
  if(callback)
    callback();
}

doSomethingIntensive( function()
{
 //And we're done, do some more
   doSomethingIntensive();
});
```

Comment: what should the call back be? what does that stand for?

Comment: As shown, its a function. `Callback` as in, a function that is called when the async operation is done. That way you know when its done.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addObjects(){
    object.setSrc(objFilename);
    object.addEventListener("onSrcSet", function() {
        object2.setSrc(objFilname2);
    }
} 

addObjects();
```

of course this implies that you use the right name for the event, instead of the arbitrarily chosen `"onSrcSet"`.

and that you meant those function calls when talking about the “second” and the “first”.

Comment: For the listener <code>onSrcSet</code> where would that listener be placed in order for it to "listen" for that function's completion?

Comment: there is not `onSrcSet` event, until you emit it yourself, what you can certainly do. my advice is to find out what event `setSrc` emits, if it does, and listen to that. all code inside the function in `addEventListener` is executed when that event is emitted.